# How to run query in SQLite database in android?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

In my SQLite database manager I can query this:

```
SELECT SUM(odometer) as odometer FROM tripmileagetable where date like '2012-07%';
```

this query returns me the total sum of the odometer colum from the table named 'tripmileagetable' of the month of july 2012, but I want to write this code in android query.

But I can't figure out how to establish this query in database.query() method, can any one help?

Comment: I believe you can use `GROUP BY` to sum the data?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
final Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT SUM(odometer) as odometer FROM tripmileagetable where date like '2012-07%';", null);
int sum = 0;
if (cursor != null) {
    try {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            sum = cursor.getInt(0);
        }
    } finally {
        cursor.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: This one gives Index out of bound exception :(

Comment: Cursor c= ourDB.rawQuery("SELECT SUM(odometer) AS odometer FROM tripmileagetable WHERE car='abdul' AND date LIKE '2012-07%'", null);
  if(c.getCount()<=0){
   return 0;
  
  }else{
   
   int sum= c.getInt(0);
   return sum; 
  }

here is the code

Comment: First you need to call c.moveToFirst(); before calling c.getInt()

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how you plan on accessing the database in Android.  You may try something like:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
String selectQuery = "select sum(odometer) as odometer from tripmileagetable where date like '2012-07%'";
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
```

The above would be used if you're using an SQLiteOpenHelper class.

If you've created the database file yourself, you could do something like:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase("/data/data/com.package.name/databases/dbname.db", null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
String selectQuery = "select sum(odometer) as odometer from tripmileagetable where date like '2012-07%'";
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
```

Do some research on SQLiteDatase, Cursor, and SQLiteOpenHelper.

This example might help you:

https://github.com/nraboy/Spyfi/blob/master/Android/src/com/nraboy/spyfi/DataSource.java

Answer (score 1):

Android fully supports [SQLite DBs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html). All the DBs you create inside your app will be accessible from all the classes of your apps (NOT outside your app!).

First of all, you should create a Java class that extends [SQLiteOpenHelper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html). Here, you have to override the *onCreate()* and *onUpdate()* methods. As one can suppose, the first is called when the DB is created, while the latter is called when the DB is modified.

```
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.content.ContentValues;


/**
 * Class DatabaseHelper.
 */
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    //Database parameters:
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "dbname";  // the name of the DB!
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE_NAME = "tripmileagetable";  // the name of the table!

    //Table attributes:
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE_ATTR_ID = "id";  // attr1
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE_ATTR_ODOMETER = "odometer";  // attr2
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE_ATTR_DATE = "date";  // attr3


    /**
     * Class constructor.
     *
     * @param context  the context.
     */
    DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String create = "CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE_NAME + " (" +
                        DATABASE_TABLE_ATTR_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                        DATABASE_TABLE_ATTR_ODOMETER + " INTEGER, " +
                        DATABASE_TABLE_ATTR_DATE + " TEXT);";

        db.execSQL( create );
    }


    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

Now, inside the new Java class, you can create custom methods to query your DB.

To write the DB you should use *getWritableDatabase()*, while to read it you should use *getReadableDatabase()*. Both of them return an *SQLiteDatabase* object, and eventually throw an *SQLiteException*.
In particular, to query your DB, there are two *SQLiteDatabase* methods available: *rawQuery* and *query* (both return a *Cursor* object).

```
/**
 * Get the sum of the odometer of a particular month and year.
 *
 * @param year  the year.
 * @param month  the month.
 * @return the sum of the odometer of the year and the month.
 */
public int sumOdometer(Integer year, Integer month) {
    //Date composition:
    String date = year.toString() + "-" + month.toString() + "%";

    //SQL query:
    String query = "SELECT SUM(" + DATABASE_TABLE_ATTR_ODOMETER + ") AS " + DATABASE_TABLE_ATTR_ODOMETER + 
                   " FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE_NAME +
                   " WHERE " + DATABASE_TABLE_ATTR_DATE + "LIKE ?";

    //Execute the SQL query:
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, new String [] {date});

    int sum = 0;
    if( cursor.moveToFirst() ) {  // moves the cursor to the first row in the result set...
        sum = cursor.getInt( cursor.getColumnIndex(DATABASE_TABLE_ATTR_ODOMETER) );
    }

    //Close the Cursor:
    cursor.close();

    return sum;
}
```

Note that SQLite automatically puts single quotes (') around the arguments (?).

You can find a good tutorial here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/119293/Using-SQLite-Database-with-Android

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [rawQuery](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) method:

```
Cursor c = database.rawQuery("SELECT SUM(odometer) as odometer FROM tripmileagetable where date like '2012-07%'", null);
```

Comment: Thanks, I am checking it and will let you know the result :)

Comment: I have done this but it getting a outofbound exception saying,

android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1

Answer (score 0):

your field is not create on your table Database, check out the field on your Table. because I have seen that problem on mine. I use SQLite Administrator to see my Database.

or if you didn't have it, look on your source code of create Database. make sure your source code is true, then you can delete your old database on file explorer (using eclipse I mean). and you can run again with new Database.