# Stored procedure use Sqlite : Android

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite, stored-procedures

My query is can we write stored procedure in sqlite so that it can be accessed from my android java class?

I have refered [Creating stored procedure and SQLite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3335162/creating-stored-procedure-and-sqlite)

And if no then is there any other way to perform this kind of activity in android??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No you cant have a stored procedure on SQLite. It is not a multi user database server like MySQL or SQL-Server. Just create a normal query and execute it. See this link for more information [How to run query in SQLite database in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11440720/how-to-run-query-in-sqlite-database-in-android).

Remember the speed benefit of a stored procedure is that it does not have to recompile and that its query plan can be generated before execution. This is great in a multi user environment but not in a single user environment like SQLite.