# Set value with result from select statement

Tags: android, database, sqlite

So I'm not exactly sure what I am doing wrong here, but I am looking to take the value from this SQLite statement and assign it to a value which i can then put into the DB)

```
String mpg = new String("select (" + gasLog.getOdometer() + " - y.odometer) / " + gasLog.getGallons() + " as mpg from tbl x, tbl y where y.odometer = (select max(z.odometer) from tbl z where z.odometer < " + gasLog.getOdometer() + ")");
        values.put(KEY_MPG, mpg);
```

However, whenever i run this, it just puts the actual statement into the cell in the database... so it inserts **"select (" + ..."**

Could someone help me with what I am doing wrong here, what do i need to do in order to get the data from this into the database, rather than the statement itself?

Thanks!

Comment: I can't see that you actually RUN the query. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11440720/how-to-run-query-in-sqlite-database-in-android

Comment: You prepare a SELECT query string, but then you put (= INSERT) it in your table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it by doing this, thanks for the tip!

```
Cursor cursor = getWritableDatabase().rawQuery("select (" + gasLog.getOdometer() + " - y.odometer) / " + gasLog.getGallons() + " as mpg from gasLog x, gasLog y where y.odometer = (select max(z.odometer) from gasLog z where z.odometer < " + gasLog.getOdometer() + ")", null);
        try {
              if (cursor.moveToFirst()) { 
                  mpg = cursor.getString(0);
              }
            } finally {
              cursor.close();
            }
        values.put(KEY_MPG, mpg);
```