# sqlite database android get all column values into string array

Tags: java, android, arrays, sqlite

I have a sqlite  database in android , for example :

Table 1 person:

- column 1: id
- column 2: name
- column 3: friends

Table 2 friends:

- column 1: id
- column 2: allFriends

the id is the same in  both tables,  id in table1 == id in table2
i want to get all the values from table2 in specific column "allFriends" by the id and insert all the String values from the column into String array / arrayList.

Comment: Seems very simple, so what have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this,**

```
  public ArrayList<String> getAllFriends(int id) {
    ArrayList<String> friendsNames = new ArrayList<>();
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = null;
    try {
        String query = "select * from person P join friends F on F.id = P.id where P.id = " + id;
        Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(query, null);
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            friendsNames.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("allFriends")));
        }
    }catch(Exception ex){
        Log.e(TAG,"Erro in geting friends "+ex.toString());
    }
    return friendsNames;
  }
```

Comment: what is the person P and friends F ?

Comment: Its an Aliases. Read more from http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp

Comment: `SELECT *` should be always avoided. Use field lists instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL query:

```
SELECT allFriends FROM friends where id == Id_from_person
```

Id_from_person - id of person who friends you want to recieve from DB.
For executing query read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11440720/how-to-run-query-in-sqlite-database-in-android).

Comment: Ofc. It is not copy-paste answer. You need to figure out a little bit by yourself to solve your question.